# Can i INSERT 2 rows or array in mysql at once

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert, row

Can i INSERT 2 rows or array in mysql at once ?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? Maybe an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can i insert 2 users by one mysql_query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
insert into table (name,other) values ('name1', 'other2'), ('name2', 'other2'), ('name3', 'other3')
```

that means you can use foreach like

```
 $values = Array();
 foreach($array as $arr)
   $values[] = "('{$arr['name']}','{$arr['name']}')";
 query("insert into table values" . implode(', ', $values ));
```

Comment: why do you concatenate? `$values[] .= "('` - it makes absolutely no sense. And once you wrote the loop itself, why didn't you escape the string right before placing it inside the query?

Comment: at first I thought to concatenate. Bu after changing to array, I just forget. Yes sure It's better to escape here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, of course.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field1,field2) VALUES (value1, value2), (value3, value4)
```

and another way that works not only in MySQL

```
INSERT INTO my_table (field1,field2)
SELECT value1, value2
UNION ALL SELECT value3, value4
UNION ALL SELECT value5, value6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (title) VALUES ('row 1'), ('row 2'), ('row 3')";
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

Should work with multiple values.

```
INSER INTO [table] ([columns]) VALUES ([values],[values]);
```